# How to change the InputSlot on a postscript file with a script (preferable on MacOS)

Tags: printing, postscript, cups

In our workflow, we create a Postscript file with all the print settings (InputSlot, PageSize, etc...), and keep this file on Disk.

If 5 copies of this document is requested, we do:

```
lp -d MyPrinter -o raw /Volumes/Nas/some_postscript_file.ps -n 5
```

notice the `-o raw` which makes sure the Postscript file is directly send to the printer.

Sometimes we want to use another tray for this print-job (e.g. InputSlot=ManualFeed), but additional options like `-o InputSlot="ManualFeed` do not work, because we're sending the file directly to the printer, so these options are not honoured by Cups (which makes sense).

So another options is to modify the Postscript file. I don't want to do some search and replace trick, I prefer a more robust solution.

Are there any scriptable applications that can modify settings made in a Postscript file?

P.S. Another option is just to create another Postscript file with the settings for the additional Tray, but with 1000's huge files it doesn't feel right to have a duplicate of the file just because of one little setting.

Comment: Don't use cups so googled the lp and lpoptions man page and found the lp command reads the ppd to find the options and there should be something like lp -d MyPrinter -n 5 -o media=??? file.ps where the options found in the ppd are placed. The lpoptions -d Myprinter command should list how to do the media tray things. Do you have the correct ppd? https://www.cups.org/doc/options.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain how you would plan to 'modify settings made in a PostScript file' without some form of search and replace.

I will concede that a search and replace solution is not going to be 100% reliable in the most general case. That's because PostScript is a programming language, so its entirely possible for the settings to be made in multiple places, and in ways which a search and replace simply isn't going to find. It works well in a closed environment (where all the PostScript programs are made by the same PostScript generator) but not in a more open workflow.

Simply prepending PostScript to select the tray you want won't work, because the program can later overwrite that request.

So your only **reliable** solution in the most general case is going to be to use a full PostScript interpreter to find the device requests and replace them. I don't know of any tool which will do that specifically. You could use Ghostscript and its ps2write device, which produces device-neutral output, but has the ability to add device-specific requests on a per-page or per-document basis.

I wouldn't recommend it though becuase it means processing the entire file and will alter the program significantly. The visual appearance should be the same, but the actual PostScript will be utterly different.

So I'd have to say that I think search and replace is your best option, given that you are creating the PostScript program yourselves, and its therefore always going to be the same.